# Select SSL certificates using Selenium web Driver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, test-strategy

I'm using `Selenium Web Driver` on `Windows 7`.

I need to test a `web application` and I've to use a `SSL certificate` to enter.

I don't know how to select the right certificate to use my application.

I'm in this situation now

[image]

**NOTE:** I've put also the `AutoIt` window to add some info.

Here

[How to select Security Certificate From security Dialog](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7640/how-to-select-security-certificate-from-security-dialog)

I've found a good answer, but I'm quite a newbie in `Java` so it's not so easy for me to understand how to use this code, that is exactly what I need to.

Could someone tell me, which libraries I've to import? Or some others alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved!

Surfing on the web I've found this post http://seleniummonk.blogspot.it/p/how-to-handle-ssl-cerificates.html that gave me the solution.

I need to use the "Firefox profile" (I use the default one ...), so I can have all the certificates I need to.

Here you're the new code that works

```
package myTestProjects;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;

public class GAMOPERA_Test_01 {

private static WebDriver driver = null;

public static void main(String[] args)  throws InterruptedException {

    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile ffProfile = profile.getProfile("default"); 

    // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
    System.out.println("Creo una nuova sessione del browser Firefox ...");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffProfile);          

    //Put a Implicit wait, this means that any search for elements on the page could take the time the implicit wait is set for before throwing exception
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // It is always advisable to Maximize the window before performing DragNDrop action
    System.out.println("Massimizzo la finestra del browser ...");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(3000L);

    //Launch the Sistema Piemonte Home Page
    System.out.println("Mi collego a Sistema Piemonte ...");
    driver.get("<my_site_url>");
    Thread.sleep(3000L);          

    // Find the element Accedi o 
    System.out.println("Accesso tramite certificato digitale ...");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/input")).click();        

    //driver.findElement(By.className("loginbutton")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000L); 

    // Print TEST = OK!!
    System.out.println("TEST = OK !!");
    //driver.quit();

        }

}
```

I hope this could be useful!

Comment: This solution does not scale, as you need to install certificate on each machine you're running the test and configure Web browser properly before running the test. Have you found a better way to use Selenium certificates?

Comment: Unfortunately no. My tests were very simple proof-of-concept.

Comment: I found a solution with PhantomJS, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution that requires no browser profile with a client certificate preconfigured but rather test must provide the certificate. The downside is that it is based on [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) Web browser implementation, not on Firefox or Chrome.

You just need to install version [2.1.1 version](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/commit/54a54dc0687a4b93562285d4f632dcafe2c7bf4f) or later. A client certificate can be provided with the following command-line parameters.

- `--ssl-client-certificate-file`: an absolute path of the client certificate file eventually containing a secret key.
- `--ssl-client-key-file`: an absolute path of a file containing just a secret key. Only needed in case of separate locations of certificate and key.
- `--ssl-client-key-passphrase`: a passphrase for the secret key.

**Preparing client certificates**

I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33569979/1218618) to prepare certificate in a proper format:

1. Extract cert for `--ssl-client-certificate-file` parameter

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -nokeys -clcerts -in cert.p12 -out src/test/resources/keys/cert.cer
   ```
2. Extract key for `--ssl-client-key-file` parameter

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -nocerts  -in cert -out src/test/resources/keys/cert.key
   ```

**Marrying with Selenium automated tests**

I was able to use it with PhantomJSWebDriver (v1.2.1). which wraps PhantomJS:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
capabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);

ImmutableMap<String, String> commandLineArguments = ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
    .put("web-security", "false")
    .put("ssl-protocol", "any")
    .put("ignore-ssl-errors", "true")
    .put("webdriver-loglevel", "DEBUG");
    .put("ssl-client-certificate-file", clientCertificateAbsolutePath)
    .put("ssl-client-key-file", clientSecretKeyAbsolutePath)
    .put("ssl-client-key-passphrase", clientSecretKeyPasshphrase)
    .build();

String[] params = commandLineArguments.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> String.format("--%s=%s", e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .toArray(new String[0]);

capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, params);
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
```

Answer (score 2):

First create a profile as I created with "Test" in Firefox using below command in CMD:

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P
```

Then import your certificate in this newly created Firefox Profile with Password used to generate the certificate. In my case this was a P12 extenstion Certificate.

Once done you can use below code in Selenium and Firefox will not popup for Certificate and you will be logged into the Portal or Website.

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile myProfile = allProfiles.getProfile("Test");
myProfile.setPreference("security.default_personal_cert", "Select Automatically");
FirefoxOptions firefoxoptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxoptions.setProfile(myProfile);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxoptions);
```

Background I am using Firefox 56.0 and Windows 7